# unable to access certains websites from my windows 8 PC

Tags: windows, internet, website

I am facing a strange problem with my windows 8 pc. I am able to access to some sites like facebook, google, wikipedia but unable to access some other sites like ains.com, youtube.com

My PC is a dual boot system with windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04 . I am able to access all the sites when I boot into ubuntu.

Please help me with the problem.

Comment: have you tried different browsers?

Comment: What is displayed by the browser when you try to open those sites?

Comment: @Ayan This is the message I receive on chrome **Unable to connect to the proxy server**

Comment: @Ben Yes ben I have tried different browsers but with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching over internet for sometime I found the solution to my problem.

The solution is:

My system was using a **proxy server**. So I had to disable it. 
I disabled it by following steps below:

1. Open **Internet Explorer**
2. Click on **settings** button and go to **Internet options**
3. On the **Connections** tab, select **LAN settings**
4. Now unselect **Use a proxy server for you LAN**

That's it my internet is now back to normal